# Cursor is not displayed on text fields

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cursor

in this page: http://www.legrandclub.net there are two text fields. In all web browser all works fine but in Internet Explorer the cursor is not displayed when I click on one of two text fields, it's possible to write some text but the cursor is not displayed.

Which could be the cause of this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're using the same background color on the input field as the cursor is (gray).

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I change the color of the cursor?

Comment: @pAkY88 You'll have to change it into a custom cursor using `cursor: url();` in your css.

Comment: I've solved the problem simply changing the text field background in a more light gray.

Comment: @pAkY88, this suggestion solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

This issue in IE < 9 was caused by adding padding to the left in my input fields. 
It was fixed by adding

```
input { padding-right:3px;}
```

to the stylesheet, where padding left was also 3px. This pushed the cusror back to where it is now visible.

Answer (score 2):

Add padding-left:2px to the text field style.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by removing

```
padding:0;
```

from CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and this is the issue: 
You should be handling the 'focus' event on that text field, so on tab focus in IE you will not see the cursor.  For that you should also bind focusin; then it will work. The following is the sample code

```
$('search-large').bind('focus focusin', function () {
```

Hope it helps...