# Input type text is not working in IE browser

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, internet-explorer

Im my project I am using angular.
Input type text is not working in IE browser. IE 11 and IE 10.

Problem -
onCLick on input box focus is coming but cursor inside the input box is not coming.

[image]

HTML Code:

```
                <tr ng-show="panel.procesChart && !emptyProcessTarget && headers.length>1">
                     <td></td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 0px;" ng-repeat="targetDet in panel.targets | limitTo:headers.length-1">
                        <input class="table-filter" type="text" ng-model='targetDet.filter'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="filter-icon">
                            <div class="filter-icon-div" ng-click="get_data()" bs-tooltip="'Filter'" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="" title=""></div>
                            <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

I tried to give :

```
$('.table-filter').on('mouse-down', function(){
      //return true;
      $(this).focus();
    });
```

But still it is not working.
I did some investigation I find IE 10 11 have some issue with it.

Please suggest me any solution or hack.
Thanks!!

Comment: I feel this not working with angular ng-repeat only..

Comment: did you tried `autofocus` attribute on input element wherever you wanted to focus on field?

Comment: Yes I tried.. its not working..

Comment: Put this before <head> tag on your html page <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Answer (score 0):

It should be `mousedown`, not `mouse-down`

```
$('.table-filter').on('mousedown', function(){
  //return true;
  $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: have you tried typing after clicking the input? if its working, take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387593/cursor-is-not-displayed-on-text-fields